# How do I find my app's exact rating in the iOS App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

On the iOS App Store, an app has a rating that is precise to ½ a star. How can I get a more precise rating? Does it exist in iTunes connect somewhere?

I noticed that the exact rating for the current version of any app is available on that [app's page](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8) in the source. You can print it in the console with the following code:

```
console.log( document.evaluate('//span[@itemprop="ratingValue"]',
                               document, 
                               null,
                               XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, 
                               null).snapshotItem(0).textContent )
```

However, I'd like to find the exact value of the `All Versions` rating.

Comment: Still no solution to this? :(

Comment: Not that I know of. I recommend asking the fastlane folks for an action for this. https://fastlane.tools/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTunes Search API does not give you enough information (Nov '18) for such detailed rating. However, it is possible to scrape that information from the web page (as you already did) but I would suggest depending on embedded Javascript object instead where you can get "ratingCountList" which contains a count for every star-rating.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [iTunes Search API](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/) to get a JSON object containing statistical information about an app on the App Store:

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=871299723

The app ID is the number at the end of the store URL. It has rating information for both the current version, as well as all versions, so hopefully that's the information you're after. :)

Comment: I only see `averageUserRating` in that report, which still seems to have only a ½ star granularity.

Comment: Upvoted because your answer is much nicer than running an xpath against the site.